# Combining neural networks in keras/theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras

I am trying to solve a ranking problem. Basically, given a query, a ranker should return a list of entities sorted according to relevance values of the entities.

I have trained a simple Neural Network in Keras (using Theano as backend) that takes in a query-entity pair (i.e, (q,e) pair) and gives a relevance rating as output (this no. shows relevance of entity to query).

The code for this is as follows:

```
# Create the model
np.random.seed(1)   # Just for reproducibility of results

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=x.shape[1],
                output_dim=50,
                init='uniform',
                activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=50,
                output_dim=50,
                init='uniform',
                activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=50,
                output_dim=10,
                init='uniform',
                activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=10,
                output_dim=1,
                init='uniform',
                activation='linear'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(x,y,nb_epoch=4500,batch_size=20,verbose=0,validation_split=0.1)
```

I want to solve another problem now, which is comparing two entities given a query. The input of the model would be  (q,e1,e2) and output of the final model should be difference between scores.

I plan to do it in the following way:
Take (q,e1) and pass it through the above Neural Net (let's call it NN1) to get a score S1 (say) and pass (q,e2) into a parallel copy of NN1 to get the score S2.
Then I want to combine these 2 values to get output as S1-S2 in the output (this is so  that I can use the MSE loss function).

Q1) How do I do this? Could someone show me the code to do this please?

Q2) This is the more important question for me. I do NOT have the score values as ground truth. I just have their differences. Is it possible to train a model to give the score given a (q,e) pair using this setup (i.e, I have (q,e1,e2) pairs and the difference between e1,e2's scores, is it possible to create a model that takes (q,e) pair as input and will give me the score as output)?

Comment: You can merge two sequential models using [the `Merge` layer](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#the-merge-layer).